# Setting Relative Paths to .xml files with Dockerfile (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, dockerfile

I have a Visual Studio Solution that has many API projects in it and then those API projects have C# library dependencies within them.  I have successfully 'dockerized' my solution.

One issue that has come up is that one of my C# libraries has xml files in them that are read at startup.  When I run these libraries as standalone the path is to the builds that C# makes, namely:

```
Debug: C:\development\gems\Backend1\DataAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
Release: C:\development\gems\Backend1\DataAPI\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1
```

The XML files are added to the Debug and Release paths above and they are read fine in the non-Dockerized environment within Visual Studio.

But with the Docker images, the path is now 'app'.  And those files are not at the base level of 'app'.  They are in:

app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1  and app/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1.

I don't want to recopy these files out to the outer level of 'app' but rather have a relative path set that I could reference and set in the Dockerfile.  Is this possible?

What solution would you propose?

Thank you!

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DataAPI/DataAPI.csproj", "DataAPI/"]
COPY ["IdentityServer/IdentityServer.csproj", "IdentityServer/"]
COPY ["ServiceDiscovery/ServiceDiscovery.csproj", "ServiceDiscovery/"]
COPY ["Data/Data.csproj", "Data/"]
COPY ["Utilities/Utilities.csproj", "Utilities/"]
COPY ["UnitConversion/UnitConversion.csproj", "UnitConversion/"]

# Trying (but failing) to copy from my /src/UnitConversion/OverrideDataNames.xml to /app
COPY ["UnitConversion/OverrideDataNames.xml", "/app"]

RUN dotnet restore "DataAPI/DataAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DataAPI"
RUN dotnet build "DataAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DataAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Don't know if I'm answering your question but when you build your image you can publish your files to whatever folder you wish `RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app`

Comment: @Jane: Thanks for responding.  I updated my question above to include the Dockerfile generated by VS-2019.  I am simply trying to copy an xml file (OverrideDataNames.xml) to the top level of app.  Please see the code now added.  That line is not working.  Any suggestions?  What am I doing wrong.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The copy overridedata names syntax looks alright. The local file must not exist.

A lot of stuff being done in that Docker, why all the csproj-file-copying? Anyways. Seems like you could get a better understanding of what is going on with a bit less cluttered dockerfile.

Consider trying this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN dotnet publish ./DataApi -c Release -o /app/build


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build /app
COPY ./UnitConversion/OverrideDataNames.xml /app
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataAPI.dll"]
```

Just one build step, `COPY . /app` copy all context into /app dotnet and then publish it. dotnet publish will run restore by itself.

Then use, as you already do in your file, a slimmer runtime image to place your app in. And in this step, try to copy whatever xml-files you need to the base /app. To move around file inside the image you would rather do `RUN cp dest src`

Hope any of the above help you out, once you've got a simple setup working you can expand on it.

Comment: My Dockerfile was fully created in Visual Studio 2019 by right clicking on my project and selecting:   Add->Docker Support...

I added in your code as is with minor change to DatAPI (all caps).  I first build my solution and then run Docker Compose from VS.  It fails with this error:

`

Error DT1001 Service 'dataapi' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish ./DataAPI -c Release -o /app/build' returned a non-zero code: 1

`

I really appreciate your help.  I am a noob to Docker as you can see.